# Upload videos to youtube android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I have tried to upload videos using the following code.But whenever i click upload it is going into INITIATION_STARTED and INITIATION_COMPLETE of ResumableUpload class.But it is not getting uploaded to youtube.I couldnt find any exception and also i couldnt understand why it is not going into MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS.

Can you help me out..

Code for getting access token and calls uploadservice from MainActivity

MainActivity.java:

```
private void tryAuthenticate() {
    if (isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    mToken = null;
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Retrieve a token for the given account and scope. It will
                // always return either
                // a non-empty String or throw an exception.
                mToken =
                        GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, mChosenAccountName, "oauth2:"
                                + Scopes.PROFILE + " " + YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE + " "
                                + YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException playEx) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(playEx.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                        MainActivity.this, REQUEST_GMS_ERROR_DIALOG).show();
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
                // Start the user recoverable action using the intent
                // returned by
                // getIntent()
                startActivityForResult(userAuthEx.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE);
                return false;
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // TODO: backoff
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), transientEx.getMessage());
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), authEx.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean hideProgressBar) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            if (hideProgressBar) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }

            if (mToken != null) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        saveAccount();
                    }
                });
            }
            loadData();
        }
    };
    task.execute((Void) null);
}



public void uploadVideo(View view) {

    if (mToken == null) {
        return;
    }
    // if an upload video is selected.
    if (mVideoData != null) {
        mDirectFragment.directLite(mVideoData, mToken);
        mButton.setEnabled(false);
        return;
    }
    // if a video is picked or recorded.
    if (mFileURI != null) {
        Intent uploadIntent = new Intent(this, UploadService.class);
        uploadIntent.setData(mFileURI);
        uploadIntent.putExtra(ACCOUNT_KEY, mChosenAccountName);
        uploadIntent.putExtra(TOKEN_KEY, mToken);
        startService(uploadIntent);
        mButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

UploadService.java

public class UploadService extends IntentService {

```
public UploadService() {
    super("YTUploadService");
}

private Uri mFileUri;
private String mToken;
private long mFileSize;

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    mFileUri = intent.getData();
    Log.d("upload service"," "+mFileUri);
    mToken = intent.getStringExtra("token");
    mFileSize = intent.getLongExtra("length", 0);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
    credential.setAccessToken(mToken);

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    YouTube youtube =
            new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
                    Constants.APP_NAME).build();

    InputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        mFileSize = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(mFileUri, "r").getStatSize();
        fileInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mFileUri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(getApplicationContext().toString(), e.getMessage());
    }
    ResumableUpload.upload(youtube, fileInputStream, mFileSize, getApplicationContext());
}
```

}

ResumableUpload.java:

public class ResumableUpload {

```
private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1001;

private static String VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT = "video/*";

public static String upload(YouTube youtube, final InputStream fileInputStream,
                            final long fileSize, Context context) {

    final NotificationManager mNotifyManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.youtube_upload))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.youtube_direct_lite_upload_started))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    String videoId = null;
    try {
        // Add extra information to the video before uploading.
        Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();


        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
        status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
        videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

        // We set a majority of the metadata with the VideoSnippet object.
        VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        snippet.setTitle("Test Upload via Java on " + cal.getTime());
        snippet.setDescription("Video uploaded via YouTube Data API V3 using the Java library "
                + "on " + cal.getTime());


        List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
        tags.add(Constants.DEFAULT_KEYWORD);
        tags.add(Upload.generateKeywordFromPlaylistId(Constants.UPLOAD_PLAYLIST));
        snippet.setTags(tags);


        videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

        InputStreamContent mediaContent =
                new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT, new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
        mediaContent.setLength(fileSize);

        YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert =
                youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata,
                        mediaContent);

        MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();


        uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

        MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
            public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                    case INITIATION_STARTED:
                        mBuilder.setContentText("Initiation Started").setProgress((int) fileSize,
                                (int) uploader.getNumBytesUploaded(), false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
                        break;
                    case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                        mBuilder.setContentText("Initiation Completed").setProgress((int) fileSize,
                                (int) uploader.getNumBytesUploaded(), false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
                        break;
                    case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                        mBuilder
                                .setContentTitle("YouTube Upload " + (int) (uploader.getProgress() * 100) + "%")
                                .setContentText("Direct Lite upload in progress")
                                .setProgress((int) fileSize, (int) uploader.getNumBytesUploaded(), false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
                        break;
                    case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                        mBuilder.setContentTitle("YouTube Upload Completed")
                                .setContentText("Upload complete")
                                        // Removes the progress bar
                                .setProgress(0, 0, false);
                        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
                    case NOT_STARTED:
                        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Upload Not Started!");
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

        // Execute upload.
        Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
        videoId = returnedVideo.getId();

    } catch (final GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        if (401 == e.getDetails().getCode()) {
            Log.e(ResumableUpload.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
            LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
            manager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.INVALIDATE_TOKEN_INTENT));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Throwable", t.getMessage());
    }
    return videoId;
}
```

}